# Does Google AppScript (GAS) supports O-Auth 2.0 Implicit Grant-Type

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-addons

I'm trying to create a new Gmail add-on using Google Apps Script and trying to access third-party, non-Google API. For that I am using O-Auth 2.0 Implicit Grant-Type for authentication.

This is how the `AuthService` looks like :

```
function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Podio O-Auth')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('Base Url')
    .setTokenUrl('Token Url')
    .setClientId('clientId')
    .setClientSecret('clientSecret')
    .setParam('redirect_uri', 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/' + scriptID + '/usercallback')
    .setScope('GLOBAL')
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
    .setParam('response_type', 'token')
    .setParam('response_mode', 'query')
    .setParam('state', getStateToken('authCallback')) // function to generate the state token on the fly
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```

The script correctly generates an URL that includes my `redirect_uri`
Auth picks up the request, generates a token, and redirects me to the scripts.google.com domain.

Once hitting `scripts.google.com`, I am redirected to an URL that includes my custom domain, e.g.

> `https://script.google.com/a/macros/[custom-domain]/d/[script-id]/usercallback#access_token=[token]&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer&state=[state]&id_token=[token]`

Which results in this error:

[image]

because the url is fragmented by `#`. If I replace the `#` with `?`, then it works as expected.

Can anyone please tell me how can I fix this issue? If not then do I have to Authorization code grant flow for this purpose ?

Note: I have used `setParam('response_type', 'token')` for Implicit Grant-Type

Comment: You may get some additional information if you inquire with the authors of the `OAuth2` library that you are using. One would think that if Apps Script did not support Implicit Grant, that the `OAuth2` library written for Apps Script would similarly not enable Implicit Grant.

Comment: @tehhowch OP did and has already received a answer from authors. He might be waiting for alternate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library currently doesn't support implicit grants. Google AppScript supports server side flow. 
So, I set the `response_type = code` and this is the working authorization service looks like:

```
function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Podio O-Auth')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('Base Url')
    .setTokenUrl('Token Url')
    .setClientId('clientId')
    .setClientSecret('clientSecret')
    .setParam('redirect_uri', 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/' + scriptID + '/usercallback')
    .setScope('GLOBAL')
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
    .setParam('response_type', 'code')
    .setParam('response_mode', 'query')
    .setParam('state', getStateToken('authCallback')) // function to generate the state token on the fly
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```

It internally first calls the autorizatiionBaseUrl and recieves the authorization code. And with this authorization code it agains makes a post request to TokenUrl to get the auth_token, refresh_token and other details.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Per your question in the `apps-script-oauth2` [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/issues/153), your particular implementation of OAuth in Apps Script (using that library) does not support Implicit Grant. Given that Apps Script executes in the server (and not the client, where implicit grant is most useful), it is not likely that the library you use will be extended to support it either.