# How to get parameters that are starting with hash character in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to auth on third party webservice. 
This service sending to my google web app request looks something like

> https://script.google.com/...exec#myvar1=1&myvar2=2

I get request in `doGet`

```
function doGet(e) {
  writeData(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

and I don't see anything containing `myvar1` in object `e`:

```
{"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"","parameters":{}}
```

But if I change `#` to `?` in url,

> https://script.google.com/...exec#myvar1=1&myvar2=2

I'll predictably see `myvar1` in `parameter` property.

Unfortunately, the url is formatted by the third party service, so I can't change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google AppScript (GAS) supports O-Auth 2.0 Implicit Grant-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671507/does-google-appscript-gas-supports-o-auth-2-0-implicit-grant-type)